# Customize navigation bar in beamer

Tags: beamer

I want to delete the bar with dull color under the navigation bar to gain more space.

MWE:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
\documentclass[french,11pt,aspectratio=1610,xcolor=table,t]{beamer}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vspace{-0.3Cm}}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
%beaver
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\title
[Short Title]{Title}

%\subtitle{} % short version unused by this template
\author
    [Person]
    {Phd defense presentation\\
    Option :Signal processing\\
    Presented by: Mr. \textbf{Person}\\
    Directed by: Pr. \textbf{Person}}
\institute
{University \\
Faculty\\
Laboratory}

\date
    [12/2019]
    {17 Décembre 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Plan}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Context}
\begin{frame}{Contexte}
Context
\end{frame}

\section{Method}
\begin{frame}{Method}
Method
\end{frame}

\section{Résult}
\begin{frame}{Résult}
résult
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to get something like that?

[image]

If that's what you meant, there is an option of the `miniframes` outer theme that can do that. Just remplace the corresponding line in your code with

```
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
```